# Why doesn't the favicon icon show in Firebug Net Panel

Tags: html, firebug, favicon

I have seen this on a lots of websites e-g: Even here:

http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

When you load all the resources for this page under Net Panel in firebug and check the images tab, it shows all the images on the page but the favicon doesnt show up. Why?

Should I be looking for it somewhere else in firebug.

Comment: There is no `favicon.ico` linked from the page you linked to. Why should the browser load something that isn't specified as a resource?

Comment: @Oded the favicon is loaded, since it appears in the tabs bar. A default location is used `/favicon.ico` when the element `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="someicon.ico />` (or similar) is not present in the HTML code

Comment: @pomeh - Which means it is probably cached and will not be re-fetched.

Comment: If you refer my link and use the preferred method 1, where favicon is used as a png, it should be there, right guys??

Comment: @Oded maybe, but cached requests should appear in the net panel too (search for `304 Not Modified`).

Comment: Exactly, cached requests too appear in firebug, but they are grayed out.

Comment: for information, this issue is also present in Chrome Developer Tools http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110449

Answer (score 9):

The first answer to [**this thread**](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mozilla.firefox.firebug/9253), by [Jan Odvarko](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/about/) *(who is a contributor to Firebug)*, seems to explain why the favicon is not displayed in Firebug's net tab *(quoting)*:

> The problem is that the network request for favicon isn't associated
>   with the page where the icon is displayed. 
> So, Firebug *(i.e. Net
>   panel)* don't know that it belongs to the page and skips the request