# Favicon request not showing in network tab of developer toolbars

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, favicon

I've set up my ASP.NET MVC app with a favicon in the Content folder (instead of the root) [along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9892941/419956). This works well, the favicon shows in all browsers.

However when I installed ELMAH I started seeing 404 errors because apparently the favicon is still being requested at the root of my site! I would love to know why this is happening and who is doing this. Under the assumption my browser was causing this I opened up the developer toolbars, here's what I find:

**Google Chrome:**
[image: Developer toolbar, network tab in Chrome]

**Internet Explorer 9:**
[image: Developer toolbar, network tab in IE9]

**Firefox:**
[image: Developer toolbar, network tab in Firefox]

All of them show 9 similar requests, but **none of them show favicon.ico requests ... *at all?*** I would've expected at least one (the one in the Content folder, which I'm seeing in my browser), and rather even two (also the one that's giving me the 404 in ELMAH).

***So, my question***: Can anyone explain why developer toolbars generally don't show favicon requests? Can this be turned on somehow or seen somewhere?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

All browsers fetch `/favicon.ico` by default to use it in the address bar, tabs, bookmarks etc. It's just a convention (and [W3C doesn't like it](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/issues.html?type=1#siteData-36)).

Using Chrome you can see this request here: `chrome://net-internals/#events`.

[image: net-internals events panel]

You can override the icon using `<link rel="shortcut icon"
 href="http://test.com/myicon.ico" />` HTML tag in the `<head>` section. This seems to prevent Chrome from checking the default location. However, even with this tag set up Chrome DevTools are not displaying `favicon.ico` as a resource that was downloaded during the page load. The reason for this may be that favicon is not used by the website, it's used by the browser. The browser request it for it's own purposes.

**[EDIT]** There is an open Chrome [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110449) classifying missing `favicon.ico` in the Network panel as a bug. 
**[EDIT]** Its also a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667348/why-doesnt-the-favicon-icon-show-in-firebug-net-panel) in a Firebug.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me. It also indeed helped me find my ELMAH 404 errors: it was in fact the browser looking for a favicon for the ELMAH *axd handler* page (as opposed to the MVC app, which turns out to be just fine).

Comment: **UPDATE**: The net-internal events are now removed. See the following:

`The net-internals events viewer and related functionality has been removed. Please use chrome://net-export to save netlogs and the external netlog_viewer to view them.`