# Why does adding a random GET parameter make favicon show?

Tags: html, favicon

I attempted adding a favicon to a site im working on, but for some reason the brower wasn't even requesting the favicon as it should, since i was getting no response from my server. I then found this identical question that solved my problem - [What are the reasons that a browser would not request favicon.ico?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564916/what-are-the-reasons-that-a-browser-would-not-request-favicon-ico)

My one questions is - How in the sweet hell dose adding this query `v=1.0` fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if it was `?v=1.0` or `?v=1000`.

When you add a GET parameter that the browser has never seen before, it forces the cache to clear. The browser probably cached the site before you added the favicon.

Comment: Yeah i think that meaks more sence. I suspected that cache was involved with the problem somehow, but i assumed that it wouldnt cache the site without a favifcon and it would get one wherever it could, but i suppose not. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: OH, of course. Sorry, im slightly new here.